# Is possible to add javascript script in facebook profile?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to add javascript script to facebook profile? 
I'd like to see alert ('hello') when I'll open my profile?

Comment: If you want this to affect just you, you can write a little browser extension. If you want it to show up for *other people* the answer is, **thankfully**, NO.

Comment: If you find a way to XSS Facebook - there's a good change they might hire you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but if you open the javascript developer console (in chrome you can hit ctl + shift + j) you can type javascript into the console and it will be executed on your Facebook page. So you can send yourself alert messages that way, or manipulate the page in any way you see fit.

I figured I'd let you know because manipulating existing pages with the developer console is an easy way to learn more about javascript and how to use it.

As the comments mention, it's impossible to make permanent changes this way, so you can experiment as much as you want without harming your Facebook profile, or anyone else's.